# FaceDetectionListener hardware support list

Tags: android, face-recognition, android-hardware

while researching the FaceDetectionListener face detection api for the android camera i found it doesn't work on the emulator or nexus 7 due to no hardware support. what devices have people gotten it to work on. The only ones I have found so far are omap 4 devices(galaxy nexus) and there is no list anywhere I can find.